# Bedeutung und Unterschied zwischen "Läuterung" und "Verklärung" im poetischen Realismus

Tags: literature

Laut Internet bedeutet

> Verklärung

so viel wie "Klarstellung".
Klargestellt oder offenbart soll, dass die der Erzählung zugrunde gelegte Wirklichkeit auf Kräften und Prinzipien beruht, die sich der unmittelbaren Wahrnehmung entziehen. Das kommt der Vorstellung des Idealismus sehr nah, dass hinter der Realität vollkommene und abstrakte Ideen wirksam sind.

Wie steht das jetzt im Zusammenhang mit

> der Läuterung?

Z.B. wurde im Gedicht von Fontane "John Maynard" der Steuermann als perfekter Held **geläutert** sprich idealisiert.

Ich sehe den Unterschied nicht, oder verstehe ich die Begriffe allgemein nicht?
Danke!!

Comment: Du solltest den Kontext, in dem diese Wort vorkommen, hier zitieren. - Dass "Verklärung" so viel wie "Klarstellung" heißen soll, ist für mich ein rechter Stolperstein. "Verklärung" ist ja fast eher schon das Gegenteil von "Klarstellung"...  also: Kontext bitte. - Ein Held, der "geläutert" aus einem Abenteuer hervorgeht, ist ethisch gereinigt; er ist ein besserer Mensch geworden.

Comment: Mit Verklärung meinte ich eher den Wortsinn also Klarstellung oder Erhellung. Im übertragenen Sinne dann sowas wie Offenbarung und Idealisierung. Also die Klarstellung bzw. Verschönerung der Wirklichkeit. Das Beispiel mit dem Läutern war aus dem Gedicht "John Maynard" (Unfall eines Bootes): Im Gedicht überleben alle und der Steuermann stirbt (Heldentot) und in der Realität sterben einige und der Steuermann überlebt. Sind jetzt nicht beide Begriffe eine Art der Idealisierung?

Comment: Verstehe *Verklärung* als "Romantisierung" und *Läuterung* als "Reinigung". Hier hat anscheinend dein Wörterbuch versagt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um die Worte zu erklären ("klar/verständlich zu machen"):

- **Verklärung**: Etwas idealisieren; etwas besser machen, als es in Wirklichkeit ist. Dabei ist oft auch eine Form von Selbstbetrug im Spiel (weil es in Wirklichkeit eben nicht so ist).
- **Klarstellung**: Etwas, das nicht richtig verstanden wurde, so formulieren, dass es verstanden werden kann.
- **Erhellung**: Veraltet für "etwas deutlicher ausdrücken, so dass es einfacher zu verstehen ist". Modern oft etwas spöttisch für den Vorgang, wenn man plötzlich etwas versteht, was man vorher nicht verstanden hat.
- **Läuterung**: Von "etwas lauter machen", wobei "lauter" ein altes Wort für "rein, sauber" ist. Das impliziert, dass es vorher in irgendeiner Form "schmutzig" war. Im übertragenen Sinn auch moralisch.

*Klarstellung* bedeutet also etwas völlig anderes als *Verklärung*. *Verklärung* und *Läuterung* sind beides Wendungen zum Positiven, aber mit einem deutlichen inhaltlichen Unterschied.

Die Vorstellung, dass *hinter* der Realität vollkommene und abstrakte Ideen wirksam sind, ist eigentlich weder *Läuterung* noch *Verklärung*. Man kann aber den Prozess, die "schmutzigen" Elemente der Realität wegzulassen, so dass nur noch die "idealen" Elemente eines Helden übrig bleiben, als *Läuterung* beschreiben. *Verklärung* hätte in diesem Fall den Beigeschmack, dass diese Idealisierung eigentlich falsch ist.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Klausur gerettet..